Custom Response for Policy Based Authorization
I have an Authorization Handler but if it fails, I want the response to be 401 with a response body.
    public class TokenValidationAuthorizationHandler: AuthorizationHandler<TokenValidationCustomRequirement>
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public TokenValidationAuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TokenValidationCustomRequirement requirement)
        {
            var httpContext = context.Resource as DefaultHttpContext;
            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                context.Fail();

            }

            var authHead =  httpContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
            var bearerToken = TokenHelper.GetToken(authHead.ToString());
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bearerToken))
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
            else
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
}

Even the context fails or succeeded, the authorizeResult.Succeeded and authorizeResult.Forbidden in the code below always result as false.
    public class TokenValidationAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
    {
        public Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext httpContext, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
        {
            if (authorizeResult.Challenged || authorizeResult.Forbidden)
            {
                var response = new BadRequestResponse("Forbidden");
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
            }

            return next(httpContext);
        }
    }


Program.cs
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, TokenValidationAuthorizationHandler>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, TokenValidationAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AuthorizationPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); // Require the user to be authenticated
        policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenValidationCustomRequirement()); // Add your custom requirement
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

When trying to check authorizeResult.AuthorizeFailure getting null exception because the AuthorizeFailure is always null.
Trying to access AuthorizeFailure null exception
What is wrong in these code and what's the real solution?

Your implementation is not laveraging policy based authorization. It sets some variables in context object. Check policy based authorization in .NET Core.
If you want to make this work, you should be checking HasSucceeded property in your HttpContext object.
I think you can refactor your code like this:
    public class TokenValidationAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext httpContext, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {
        if (!httpContext.HasSucceeded)
        {
            var response = new BadRequestResponse("Forbidden");
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
        }

        return next(httpContext);
    }
}


How to make the code to leverage the policy based authorization more?

There is no 'context' defined in the solution you provided.

It's httpContext, i fixed the typo.

httpContext doesn't have a method HasSucceeded

Firstly, when we want to custom the response of Policy-based authorize, we could follow this tutorial to add custom implement for IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler just like what you already did. I tried your codes in my side which worked well in my side, and you mentioned  authorizeResult.Succeeded and authorizeResult.Forbidden in the code below always result as false, so that I recommend you to change the if validation.
if (authorizeResult.Forbidden
    && authorizeResult.AuthorizationFailure!.FailedRequirements
        .OfType<TokenRequirement>().Any())
{
    // Return a 404 to make it appear as if the resource doesn't exist.
    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
    var response = "it's Forbidden";
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
    return;
}


=============================================
When I test with code below,  if (authorizeResult.Forbidden && authorizeResult.AuthorizationFailure!.FailedRequirements.OfType<TokenRequirement>().Any()) is false, then my result will be 403 without custom response.
public class TokenHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TokenRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TokenRequirement requirement)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

But if I comment context.Fail(); and make it just return task complete, then I will have my custom result.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, TokenHandler>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<
    IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, SampleAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    //options.InvokeHandlersAfterFailure = false;
    options.AddPolicy("RequireAdmin", policy =>
    policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenRequirement()));
});


Your AuthorizationHandler method is the same as i provided? because the authorizeResult.AuthorizationFailure is being resulted as null on my side which is being crashed when accessing FailedRequirements

I test with context.Fail(); and return Task.CompletedTask; which both worked in my side.  Pls try authorizeResult.AuthorizationFailure!.FailedRequirements         .OfType<TokenRequirement>().Any() and see whether it worked or not

No it doesn't work as it is being returned as null. See the picture above where it crashed. Do you have any GitHub link for the solution that is working?

I test again with my sample last week. I updated my post

Still doesn't work when commenting the context.Fail()

I'm not able to reproduce your issue in my side based on your code snippet, and my code snippet worked well in my side but it doesn't work in your side...

Do you have a link for a repo that have the code snippet?

Here's the link I referred to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-8.0
